# multivariate KNN prediction

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

So, I have code that works for knn.predict() if I have data that has 1 feature to predict the next outcome.  To put this into context, I have stock data (Open, High, Low, Close) where I use "Open" as "X" data and "Close" as "Y" data and knn.predict will predict the next value of Y.

When I try to use "Open, High, Low" columns (3 features) for my X data, I get the following error:

```py
File "sklearn\neighbors\binary_tree.pxi", line 1294, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query
ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension
```

I believe it's because of my X.shape and Y.shape where X is not the same size as Y but I don't understand how to fix it.  How do you use KNN for multifeature analysis if X and Y must be the same size?

Some of the Code:

```
df = df[['Date','Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
df.head()

# Predictor Variables
df['Open'] = df.Open
df['High'] = df.High
df['Low'] = df.Low
df['Close'] = df.Close
df = df.dropna()
#Data = np.delete(arr = df, obj=0, axis = 0)
X = np.array(df.ix[:, 2:6])
#X.head()
print X.shape

# Target Variable
Y = np.where(df['Close'].shift(-1)>df['Close'],1,-1)
#print (Y)

#Predict
u = df['Close'].iloc[-1]
#print u
new_prediction = knn.predict(u)
print new_prediction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For training, you're using

```
X = np.array(df.ix[:, 2:6])
```

i.e., a matrix with 6 - 2 = 4 columns, meaning that the neighbors are 4-tuples.

For predicting, you're using

```
u = df['Close'].iloc[-1]
```

which is a scalar.

The nearest neighbor is undefined, and sklearn is very unhappy.

Comment: Okay i see.  So X.shape prints as (43511, 4) so isn't this 4-tuples? If i change my code to X = df[['Open'']], then the code works fine.  Is this because now X is also a scalar?

Comment: Almost. `df[['Open']]` is not an array of Scalars, but rather an array of 1-tuples. Numpy distinguishes between 2-dimensional arrays which have dimension 1 along some axis, 1 dimensional arrays, and scalars. Other than that, yes.